# How to open google maps app with a dropped pin ? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have this code to open Google Maps App with specific location and it's working but what I need is to drop a pin on that location, is it possible ?

```
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {

                UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:
                    "comgooglemaps://?center=\(self.location.coordinate.latitude),\(self.location.coordinate.longitude)&zoom=14&views=traffic")!)
            } else {
                print("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
            }
```

How to to do this ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> q: The query string for your search.

It creates a marker in given coordinates. Try this

```
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://?center=\(self.location.coordinate.latitude),\(self.location.coordinate.longitude)&zoom=14&views=traffic&q=\(self.location.coordinate.latitude),\(self.location.coordinate.longitude)")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        print("Can't use comgooglemaps://")
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought `q` only for search but also I remember that you can search by coordinates , Thank you it worked.

Comment: Any way to show location name instead of coordinates in the marker ?

Comment: Vinoth Vino, did you find a way for that?

Answer (score 7):

Here is the **Swift 5** solution, where you can be sure that the map is shown in the browser if the Google Maps app is not installed or in the Google Maps app if it is installed on the device, both cases with the pin of the location.

```
 if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!) {
     UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://?center=\(latitude),\(longitude)&zoom=14&views=traffic&q=\(latitude),\(longitude)")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
 } else {
     UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:\(latitude),\(longitude)&zoom=14&views=traffic&q=\(latitude),\(longitude)")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

First open `Info.plist` as *Source Code* (Righ Click on file Info.plis, then select Source Code) and add this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>googlechromes</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

Next to make it easier to open Google Maps, create function like this one:

```
func openGoogleMaps() {
    if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:
            "comgooglemaps://?center=\(myLatitude),\(myLongitude)&zoom=14&views=traffic")!)
    } else {
        print("Can't use comgooglemaps://")
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to open Google Maps with given coordinate, you just call the function `openGoogleMaps()`.

For more check [Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme) and [Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_7_declare_the_url_schemes_used_by_the_api)

Answer (score 5):

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?center=\(self.latitude),\(self.longitude)")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
         print("Opening in Apple Map")

    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.latitude, self.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.02))
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    let options = [
        MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: region.center),
        MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: region.span)]
    mapItem.name = theLocationName
    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
    }
```

Use this code for opening in google map if it's installed else open in default apple map.

Answer (score 2):

> Swift 3 , iOS 10

```
let lat = 0.0
let lon = 0.0

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?center=\(lat),\(lon)&zoom=14&views=traffic&q=loc:\(lat),\(lon)")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    print("Can't use comgooglemaps://")
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:\(lat),\(lon)&zoom=14&views=traffic")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://?center=\(self.location.coordinate.latitude),\(self.location.coordinate.longitude)&zoom=14&views=traffic&q=\(self.location.coordinate.latitude),\(self.location.coordinate.longitude)")!)
} else {
    print("Can't use comgooglemaps://")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is much simpler to do in 2019: just use the universal link

```
URL(string: "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=\(lat),\(lng)")
```

See the complete documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide .

Answer (score 1):

This simple URL scheme works for me

```
URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?q=\(lat),\(lng)")
```

P.S. But don't forget to add `comgooglemaps` URL scheme to Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line in info.Plist file

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>googlechromes</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

code here:

```
if dicDetails.hasValueForKey("latitude") && dicDetails.hasValueForKey("latitude") {
        if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://?center=\(dicDetails.stringValueForKey("latitude")),\(dicDetails.stringValueForKey("longitude"))&zoom=14&views=traffic&q=\(dicDetails.stringValueForKey("latitude")),\(dicDetails.stringValueForKey("longitude"))")!, options: convertToUIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKeyDictionary([:]), completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                 //https://www.google.com/maps/@
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"https://www.google.com/?q=\(dicDetails.stringValueForKey("latitude")),\(dicDetails.stringValueForKey("longitude")),15z")!)
            }
        } else {
            //print("Can't use comgooglemaps://")
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"https://www.google.com/?q=\(dicDetails.stringValueForKey("latitude")),\(dicDetails.stringValueForKey("longitude")),15z")!)
        }
    }
```