# Google map shows location, but not showing marker - swift4

Tags: ios, google-maps, location, swift4

I am trying to show the location of myLatitude and myLongitude on google maps application. But it is not showing the blue marker, but just is being zoomed to the location.

I could not find the solution from:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme

```
    if let url = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?center=\(myLatitude),\(myLongitude)&zoom=14") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
    }
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43276664/7250862

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
let MyMarker = GMSMarker()
let latitude = valueOf["latt"]?.trimmed   // Your Latt
let longitude = valueOf["long"]?.trimmed  // Your Long
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: Double(latitude!)!,longitude: Double(longitude!)!,zoom: self.zoom)

MyMarker.position = camera.target
```

Comment: I am not integrating google maps inside my project, rather I am redirecting it to google maps App.